# python spark aggregate function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying aggregate function

```
num = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
seq = (lambda x,y:(x[0]+y,x[1]+1))
comb = (lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]))
res = num.aggregate((0,0),seqOp=seq,combOp=comb)
print("res is ",res)
```

and the result is

```
res is  (15, 5)
```

But if I change the third line of previous code to :

```
comb = (lambda x,y:(y[0],y[1]))
```

the result is still same

```
res is  (15, 5)
```

It shouldn't be this since I didn't merge two resulting tuple.

if I change it again to

```
comb = (lambda x,y:(x[0],x[1]))
```

the result is:

```
res is  (0, 0)
```

May someone explain it?

Comment: not at all. I didn't change the (0,0). I change the combOp function.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Spark you are working with?  I just tried this on Spark 2.1 and for `comb = (lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]))` the result was `(15,5)` while for `comb = (lambda x,y:(y[0],y[1]))` the result was `(5,1)`.

Comment: BTW, I had also tested this on Spark 1.6.3.

Comment: you may try spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7, which I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by myself.
this is happened in standalone mode where x is (0,0) and y is (15,5).